# C++ template and inheritance, function not replaced in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Here I attached a minimal case, where in child class, `cmp` will replace the one in parent class, but it doesn't work, it always calls the one from the parent

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        void tell(T a, T b)
        {
            std::cout << (cmp (a, b) ? a : b) << " is better" << std::endl;
        }
    protected:
        bool cmp (T & a, T & b)
        {
            return a > b;
        }
};

template <typename T>
class B: public A<T>
{
    protected:
        bool cmp (T & a, T & b)
        {
            return a < b;
        }
};

int main ( int argc , char **argv ) 
{
    B<int> b;
    // should be: 3 is better here
    b.tell(5, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cmp` function must be declared `virtual` in `A`.

```
protected:
    virtual bool cmp (T & a, T & b)
    {
        return a > b;
    }
```

It will implicitly remain virtual in derived classes, although I'd explicitly declare `cmp` virtual in `B` as well, for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 3):

You must declare polymorphic functions `virtual`. Otherwise you will not get polymorphic behaviour

```
virtual bool cmp (T & a, T & b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make `cmp` a virtual function in the base class:

```
virtual bool cmp (T & a, T & b);
```